# How do I run my main.go file without having to run them separately outside of the containers?

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I have a `main.go` file that I use to run an app that starts a server that exposes a port where I can run endpoints from. I was trying to dockerise it and got as far as making working containers that hold the app and the db, but I still seem to have to run `go run main.go` after running `docker-compose up -d`.

```
// present folder structure
.
├── cities.json // holds records of all city names
├── docker-compose.yaml 
├── dockerfile
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── localmon.sh // bash script that does a mongoimport to import all records from cities.json into the db
├── main.go
└── README.md
```

I've been told I may have to either map a volume know where that lives and have it execute. Another option (more complex) is a bash script (or both?)

I'm kind of unsure as to how to go about this or what I'm supposed to do with my compose file and dockerfile as it is at the moment.

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    hostname: mongo-test
    container_name: "mongo-test"
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - app_test
    ports: 
        - "8001:27017" 
    #   - "27017:27017"
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ".mongodata:/data/db"
  
  app: 
    hostname: app-test
    container_name: "app"
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    networks:
      - app_test
    ports: 
      - "54321:8080"
      # - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env

networks:
  app_test: {}
```

```
FROM golang:1.17.5-alpine3.15

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copies and downloads necessary dependencies
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o main .

# Port 8080 exposed for use
EXPOSE 8080

# Command that starts the container
CMD ["./main"]
```

```
env file that holds some DB related stuff for the main.go file to use.

DB_URI=mongodb://mongo-test:8001
CITY_DB=nht_cities
COL_USER=user
COL_CITY=city
USER_AUTH_TOKEN=50dba...
```

```
// localmon.sh

#! /bin/bash
mongoimport --host 192.168.0.101  --port 8001 --db nht_cities --collection city --type json --file ./cities.json
```

`docker-compose logs` after running a recent `docker-compose up -d`

```
Attaching to mongo-test, app
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:08:52Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:02Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:13Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:24Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:34Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:45Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:09:55Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:06Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:17Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:27Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:38Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:48Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
app    | time="2022-01-03T20:10:59Z" level=fatal msg="server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo-test:8001, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 172.23.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused }, ] }"
... goes on for a bit

mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.360+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.362+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.362+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.362+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.363+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.363+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.363+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.363+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.364+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongo-test"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.364+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.5","gitVersion":"d65fd89df3fc039b5c55933c0f71d647a54510ae","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.364+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.364+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"}}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.365+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.365+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.365+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7178M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.942+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240522:942716][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:42.968+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240522:968493][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.010+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:10614][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Main recovery loop: starting at 9/5120 to 10/256"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.056+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:56865][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.084+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:84544][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.108+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:108553][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.108+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:108603][1:0x7f62a3693c80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.110+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240523:110204][1:0x7f62a3693c80], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 616"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.115+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":750}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.115+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.116+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.117+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.120+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.124+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.126+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.126+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.127+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:08:43.127+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:09:43.122+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240583:122644][1:0x7f629ae81700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 3, snapshot max: 3 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 616"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:10:43.134+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240643:134518][1:0x7f629ae81700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 6, snapshot max: 6 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 616"}}
mongo-test | {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-03T20:11:43.147+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1641240703:147808][1:0x7f629ae81700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 8, snapshot max: 8 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 616"}}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

var client mongo.Client                                                                       // mongo client from setup declared globally
var characterRunes = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") // character runes used for creation of tokens

func setup() { // Setup for mongodb connection using mongo drivers. Returns client.
    clientOptions := options.Client().
        ApplyURI(os.Getenv("DB_URI"))
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    clientLocal, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err, "This is from the first one")
    }
    err = clientLocal.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err, "This is from the second one")
    }
    fmt.Println("MongoDB started successfully!")
    client = *clientLocal
}

// model for user endpoint
type User struct {
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    AccessToken string `json:"token"`
}

type City struct {
    Name string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load() // Loads environment variables from .env
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    setup()
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/user", UserAuth(createUser)).Methods("POST")  // Route for registering new users
    r.Handle("/suggest", APIAuth(searchCity)).Methods("GET") // Route for searching cities within DB

    fmt.Println("Server running at port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))

}

func createUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // POST request that takes in user details, generates an access token and inserts them into the DB
    w.Header().Add("content-type", "application/json")

    var user User
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)
    userCollection := client.Database(os.Getenv("CITY_DB")).Collection(os.Getenv("COL_USER")) // Holds 'user' collection from DB
    user.AccessToken = generateToken()                                                        // Generated access token is assigned to user struct

    _, err := userCollection.InsertOne(context.Background(), user) // Details are inserted into the collection
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Fatalln(err, "Failed to create user.")
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)

}

func searchCity(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // GET request that takes in a url param and returns a list of cities from the DB
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    values := r.URL.Query()
    city := values["city_name"]                                                               // Assigns url param from route `/suggest?city_name=` to 'city'
    cityCollection := client.Database(os.Getenv("CITY_DB")).Collection(os.Getenv("COL_CITY")) // Holds 'city' collection from DB

    if len(city) == 0 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "City name cannot be empty!"}`))
        return
    }

    filter := bson.D{ //Regex filter for querying the input through the DB
        primitive.E{
            Key: "all_names", Value: primitive.Regex{
                Pattern: city[0], Options: "i",
            },
        },
    }

    cursor, err := cityCollection.Find(r.Context(), filter) // Query to find city is declared with cursor
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "Could not execute cursor into query."}`))
        return
    }

    var cityList []City
    for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) { // Runs through each document entry in DB to see if regex matches
        var cities City
        err := cursor.Decode(&cities)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "Could not run cursor."}`))
            return
        }
        cityList = append(cityList, cities) // List of cities is appended to cityList
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if len(cityList) == 0 {
        w.Write([]byte(`{"cities": []}`))
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(cityList)

}

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) // Creates a new seed for randomising the access token
}

func genString(n int) string { // Generates a randomised string from the character runes
    b := make([]rune, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = characterRunes[rand.Intn(len(characterRunes))]
    }
    return string(b)
}

func generateToken(n ...int) string { // Generates a token for when a new user registers their details
    characters := 32

    if len(n) > 0 {
        characters = n[0]
    }

    randString := genString(characters)

    h := sha256.New()
    h.Write([]byte(randString))
    generatedToken := h.Sum(nil)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", generatedToken)

}

func APIAuth(endpoint func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) http.Handler { // Middleware to check if access token is contained within header when running searchCity
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        accessToken := r.Header.Get("x-api-key")

        // Checks token in db
        usersCollection := client.Database(os.Getenv("CITY_DB")).Collection(os.Getenv("COL_USER"))
        filter := bson.D{
            primitive.E{
                Key: "accesstoken", Value: accessToken,
            },
        }

        var user User
        err := usersCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&user)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, `Unauthorized access`, http.StatusUnauthorized)
        } else if len(accessToken) == 0 {
            http.Error(w, `Unauthorized access`, http.StatusUnauthorized)
        } else {
            endpoint(w, r)
        }
    })
}

func UserAuth(endpoint func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) http.Handler { // Middleware to check if user registering has appropriate auth token
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        accessToken := r.Header.Get("x-access-token")
        if len(accessToken) == 0 {
            http.Error(w, "Unauthorized access, no token", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        if accessToken != os.Getenv("USER_AUTH_TOKEN") {
            http.Error(w, "Unauthorized access", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        endpoint(w, r)
    })
}
```

`netstat -tulpn` with containers running

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.101:40571     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/rygel          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5054          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2967/python3        
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:41599        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/rygel          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46624         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2358/kited          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34179         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/rygel          
tcp        0      0 172.23.0.1:39273        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3086/rygel          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54321           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8001                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      3083/gnome-remote-d 
tcp6       0      0 :::54321                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 172.17.0.1:41320        0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50334           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 172.17.0.1:1900         0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 172.23.0.1:1900         0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 192.168.0.101:1900      0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1900          0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52502         0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 172.23.0.1:45184        0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 192.168.0.101:53552     0.0.0.0:*                           3086/rygel          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::42415                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

Comment: Hi Lazlo, I'm afraid I don't understand what the problem is. Could you please tell what you want to do and what goes not as you expect?

Comment: Why do you do go run main.go outside of the container? Which command do you use to start the container with your app?

Comment: Hi, Andrey. What I do is run `docker compose up -d` and start the containers. That starts the app and the mongo-test db from within the compose file. After that, I run `go run main.go` to get the app working but that shouldn't be the case. I want that portion already handled by the container instead of me having to do it manually.

 Basically, I want the `main.go` file to run as part of the `docker-compose up -d` command. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Running the app outside the container defies the purpose of creating the container. It's not a workaround :)
You correctly specify CMD ["./main"] in your dockfefile. It seems like your app is crashing on start (cannot connect to the DB?). Please look at the logs with the "docker-compose logs <service name>" command.

Comment: Another question: how do you test that your app is started?

Comment: I have a command that prints out that the server has started and runs on the port specified. Should I post the logs as well as my `main.go` file? Maybe there's more info to be found there. Although, I'm worried if I edit my question that it'll delete the comments since that is what happened last time I did it.

Comment: The comments should stay intact. Please, share the output of the container and the real symptom of the problem: what makes you think that your app is not running (commands and outputs, please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, change the following line in the `.env` file:

```
DB_URI=mongodb://mongo-test:8001
```

to

```
DB_URI=mongodb://mongo-test:27017
```

The containers run in the same container network when you start them with the `docker compose up` command. That means you need to specify the container port instead of the host port. The container port always goes second in the Docker kingdom: `<host port>:<container port>`.

Comment: Ah, there's an issue where there's a mongo instance running directly on the host, _not_ in a container. That's why I stuck with 8001. I can edit the `netstat -tulpn` logs in to show you.

Comment: @Lazlo, the docker-compose.yaml clearly instructs Docker to launch mongo in a Docker container. What makes you think that it doesn't work. It's really confusing.

Comment: Please, try to follow the recommendation from the answer and let me know if that worked.

Comment: My apologies, upon re-reading what you've said multiple times, I think I figured it out and what you said did work. My brain had trouble following along for some reason, maybe because I'm tired and it's nearly 3am here. Been at this for a while now.
My urls for the endpoints are now at `http://localhost:54321`. Still trying to figure out how to import the records from `cities.json` since I'm not sure which host and port to use anymore within the .sh file.

Comment: No worries at all. It's a lot of stuff to process. I wish you good luck with all that :)